# Unable to apply a SAS macro to a column

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to apply a macro I have written to each individual row in SAS

```
DATA cars1;
INPUT make $ model $ mpg weight price;
CARDS;
AMC Concord 22 2930 4099
AMC Pacer   17 3350 4749
AMC Spirit  22 2640 3799
Buick Century 20 3250 4816
Buick Electra 15 4080 7827
;
RUN; 

%macro calculate1 (var_name, var_value);
%If &var_name < 20 %then
%do;
&var_value + &var_name;
%end;
%else %if &var_name >= 20 %then
%do;
&var_value - &var_name;
%end;
%mend ;

Data cars2; Set cars1;
varnew = %calculate1(mpg, weight);
Run;
```

When I run this code I get a difference between the two columns even when the MPG values are <20 when according to the code I want the sum of the columns if the value in the MPG column is < 20.

I know I could use If conditions using the columns but I want try to use macros to do this.

Please help me apply my macro on the columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely do not need to macro code yet.

Macro writes SAS source code before run-time, it does not evaluate data step expressions at runtime.

Learn to write DATA Step code before attempting to abstract it to macro.

**DATA Step**

This *might* contain source code statements (the if/then/else) that you want macro to *generate*

```
data cars2;
  * calculate;
  if mpg < 20 then varnew = weight + mpg;
  else
  if mpg >= 20 then varnew = weight - mpg;
run;
```

How would this be abstracted ?  Determine which components of the if/then/else would be reused in a different context or with different variables.  If you can't determine re-use, don't code a macro.

Consider abstraction #1 (as pseudo-code) that is to generate a complete statement

```
  if PARAMETER_2 < 20 then RESULT_VAR = PARAMETER_1 + PARAMETER_2;
  else
  if PARAMETER_2 >= 20 then RESULT_VAR = PARAMETER_1 - PARAMETER_2;
```

or abstraction #2 that is to generate source code for an expression

```
  ifn (PARAMETER_2 < 20, PARAMETER_1 + PARAMETER_2, PARAMETER_1 - PARAMETER_2)
```

But why hardcode `20` into the macro ? Why not make that a parameter as well ? If you go that route the abstraction is too much and is templating actual language elements that should be used in a non-macro way.  (One might suppose in a purely functional language such as LISP there is no abstraction too much)

Abstraction #1 as macro

```
%macro calculate(result_var, parameter_1, parameter_2);
  /* generate DATA Step source code, using the passed parameters */

  if &PARAMETER_2 < 20 then &RESULT_VAR = &PARAMETER_1 + &PARAMETER_2;
  else
  if &PARAMETER_2 >= 20 then &RESULT_VAR = &PARAMETER_1 - &PARAMETER_2;
%mend;

data cars2;
  %calculate(varnew,weight,mpg);
run;
```

Abstraction #2 as macro

```
%macro calculate(parameter_1, parameter_2);
  /* generate source code that is valid as right hand side of assignment */

  ifn (&PARAMETER_2 < 20, &PARAMETER_1 + &PARAMETER_2, &PARAMETER_1 - &PARAMETER_2)
%mend;

data cars2;
  varnew = %calculate(weight,mpg);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you @Richard! Your explanation has helped me a lot.